# Which function does loadingCache call when .refreshAfterWrite() ends?

Tags: java, caching, guava, resteasy, google-guava-cache

I am trying to create a cache using Google LoadingCache.

My program uses another rest service. I am wondering if it's possible to configure the cache such that once the .refreshAfterWrite ends it calls the loadAll function.

Essentially I'd like to do something like what appears on number 8 in  this link once the refreshAfterWrite timer ends.
http://www.baeldung.com/guava-cache

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to refresh _other keys_ after one key expires?

Comment: (It calls [`reload`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader.html#reload(K,%20V)).)

Comment: It sounds like you're expecting `refreshAfterWrite` to have a timer thread and you want to reload the entire cache. It doesn't work that way and you should use your own timer thread. See [docs](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#refresh) for details.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I was hoping to refresh all keys at once since the API I can use brings all of the data at once since they all have to update at the same time but based on Ben's response I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "refreshAfterWrite timer", nor any other background cleanup work being managed by the `Cache` - as the [docs](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#refresh) say:

> `refreshAfterWrite` will make a key *eligible* for refresh after the specified duration, but a refresh will only be actually initiated when the entry is queried.

If you want to invoke `loadAll()` after a certain period of time you should [schedule a task to do so](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#when-does-cleanup-happen).